# How to use python to retrieve an url from an excel column and then open it with chrome and login password?

Tags: python, excel, selenium, openpyxl

I am an absolute noob and I have the following scenario:
I have an Excel file with a column filled with +4000 URLs each one in a different cell. The url links to facebook-like page where a user would be asked to set a password. I need to use Python to retrieve each url, open it with Chrome, set a specified password that will be the same one in all cases, and then validate it lands on the home page.

Step by step:

1 Openpyxl opens excel spreadsheet
2 Find column with urls
3 Make a list of urls?
3 Get chrome to open the first url 
4 Find password field 
5 Set a password that will be the same one for all users
6 Confirm it lands on homepage 
7 Repeat with next url in the column until the end 
8 Preferably get a report to confirm number of fails if any

So far this is my code:

```
import openpyxl
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('Test Sheet.xlsx')
type(wb)

openpyxl.workbook.workbook.Workbook

print (wb.sheetnames)

['Users']

wb['Users']

<Worksheet "Users">

for x in range (2,4):
print(x,sheet.cell(row=x,column=3).value)

# which returns 

2 www.somefacebookurl.com
3 www.someotherfacebookurl.com


# then I found this example for getting Selenium to open a given url 

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# now here I need driver.get (I've seen browser.get may also work) to open 
  each url one by one so I understand I need to make a list from my previus 
  range

driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("pycon")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
driver.close()
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Please read the openpyxl tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

For reading things from excel you can use pandas, that works well. So lets say your file is - file.xlsx and your data is in sheet with name "sheet1", the links are in column named "links". You can have the following code to get its content into a pandas dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
exceldata = pd.read_excel("file.xlsx",sheet_name = "sheet1")
for idx in exceldata.index:
   print(exceldata['links'][idx]))
   ## Do your selenium tasks here for opening and logging into the fetched link.
```

I am answering in a bit of hurry, so if you need help related to tasks after getting link from excel just let me know in comment. Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: For just readin XLSX files, it makes more sense to just use openpyxl.

Comment: @CharlieClark yes you are right perhaps, its just that at that point the solution above came in my mind. :)

Comment: I have updated the code using openpyxl but now I have trouble to get selenium to get the urls. Every example I find uses one specified url and I need to work with a list of urls or a range of values taken from the spreadsheet for that matter.